# Hotpoint double oven model identification

Tags: repair

Can anyone identify this oven in the attached photo please. The stick on label seems to have gone missing.[image]

Comment: There should be a stamped serial or manufacturing code you can refer to.

Comment: OK thank you for that, but where might I find it. I have even looked on the bottom of the thing and can find nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd guess back panel, possibly inside an electrical access plate.